# passing parameters to rails back end from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

I am trying to pass an API route to rails for the server to perform the call instead of the client. I get a 404 not found when I try to do this. From the console it works find when I am passing this route to the method. However not from the ajax call. Here is my controller method:

```
    def identification
       @link = params[:link]
       @response = MotorClient.new.response_from_path(@link)
       render json: @response
    end
```

Here is my route:

```
    get '/identification/:link', to: 'vehicles#identification', on: :collection
```

Here is my ajax:

```
    handleRoute: function (e) {
    this.handleChange(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    var options = e.target.options;
    var route = "";
    for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (options[i].selected) {
            route = (options[i].dataset.route);
            console.log(route)
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '/vehicles/identification/',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {"link":encodeURIComponent(route)},
                success: function (data) {
                    this.props.getMakes(data);
                }.bind(this),
            })
        }
    }
},
```

When I console.log the route I get the correct string like this "/v1/Information/YMME/Years/2012/Makes/56/Models" and Like I said from the rails console it works but I can't get the parameter correctly this is what I get on the javascript console when I do thru the ajax call:

```
     GET http://localhost:3000/vehicles/identification/?link=%252Fv1%252FInformation%252FYMME%252FYears%252F2012%252FMakes 404 (Not Found)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your route is expecting the `link` to be a segment in the URL path instead of a query string variable: `/identification/:link` -- Try dropping the `/:link` or appending the encoded link at the end of your URL when making an AJAX call back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) which escapes the link string. It is better to escape data in such way, so I'm thinking you better to handle escaped string format at API side.

There is another way: using 'post' instead of 'get' ajax type. Thus, you could drop escaping part and pass a pure string as 'link' property.

Comment: The link is already encoded via `encodeURIComponent` if you look at the code in the question.